# Get the receiver's number from an SMS on Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sms

I am using the below code to get originatingAddress (the sender's number).

```kotlin
import android.provider.Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent

fun getFullMessage(messageParts: Array<SmsMessage>): CompleteSmsMessage {
  messageParts = getFullMessage(getMessagesFromIntent(intent))
  messageParts.last().also { part ->
    return CompleteSmsMessage(
      originatingAddress = part.originatingAddress,
      body = messageParts
          .map { it.messageBody }
          .reduce { acc, body -> acc + body }
    )
  }
}
```

Since I have multiple SIM slots on my phone, I'd like to get the receiver's number as well. I couldn't find any relevant document here: `https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage#getDisplayOriginatingAddress()`

Is it possible to get the receiver's number? How?

Answer (score 1):

The incoming intent contains `subscription` variable, this is the SIM slot:

```
val slotId = intent.getIntExtra("subscription", -1)
```

Comment: Ok, so technically speaking I can only get the slot number rather than the actually phone number, right?